# require path in php

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
require("\create_form\view.php");
```

and receiving the following error:

> Warning: require(\create_formiew.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\training\school\STU001_MAIN.php on line 67

You can see from the error message that "require(\create_formiew.php)" has a missing "\v", whereas I wrote "\create_form\view.php".

What's the problem?

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Either escape the backslashes in double quotes, or just use forward slashes. Forward slashes work on Windows too.

Also you probably don't want to use an absolute path.

```
require("./create_form/view.php");
```

Or make it relative to the [document root](http://www.google.com/search?q=document%20root) with:

```
require("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/create_form/view.php");
// Note: Use without key quotes only in double quoted string context!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR' to avoid errors with system specific file paths.

Answer (score 1):

`\v` is the [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for a vertical tab.

Either use single quotes in your strings or escape the backslashes (`\\`) to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
require("/create_form/view.php");
```

Comment: Did you mean: "forward slash"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using double (\) backslashes between directorys:

require("\create_form\view.php");